# Let ,  be sets. Show that if (∪) ⊆ () ∪ (), then either ⊆  or  ⊆ .

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

**Let,  be sets.

**Show that if (∪) ⊆ () ∪ (),then either  ⊆  or  ⊆ .****

This is my attempt at the proof, but I am not sure if I have given the correct justifications, especially in line 10-11, because

the definition of $\cup$ is **x $\in$ A $\lor$ x $\in$ B $\rightarrow$ x $\in$ A $\cup$ B**, but does this imply **(x $ \not \in$ A $\land$ x $\not \in$ B $\rightarrow$ x $ \not \in$ A $\cup$ B)?**

I know that  **(x $ \not \in$ A $\land$ x $\not \in$ B $\rightarrow$ x $ \not \in$ A $\cup$ B)** in line 11 is true, but I am not sure if I should be justifying it using the definition of $\cup$. If no, then what should I use instead? Or do I need to justify line 11 at all?

Thank you!

Comment: If you are not very convinced, then try to justify it properly. If you are convinced that it follows directly from the definition of $\cup$, then it is ok (because indeed, it follows directly from the definition of $\cup$).

Comment: @TheSilverDoe right, otherwise the proof is valid?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why going for the contrapositive.

Suppose that $\mathscr{P}(A\cup B)\subseteq \mathscr{P}(A)\cup\mathscr{P}(B)$. Then either $A\cup B\in\mathscr{P}(A)$ or $A\cup B\in\mathscr{P}(B)$, that translates to “either $A\cup B\subseteq A$ or $A\cup B\subseteq B$”. Finish the argument.

On the other hand, your proof is correct. To rewrite in in a shorter form, if $A\not\subseteq B$ and $B\not\subseteq A$, there are $x\in A\setminus B$ and $y\in B\setminus A$.

The set $\{x,y\}$ belongs to $\mathscr{P}(A\cup B)$, but it belongs neither to $\mathscr{P}(A)$ nor to $\mathscr{P}(B)$. Therefore
$$
\mathscr{P}(A\cup B)\not\subseteq \mathscr{P}(A)\cup\mathscr{P}(B)
$$
Now sit back and compare the two proofs.